# Detecting Device/Desktop and Redirecting

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Below mentioned is my htaccess file that I have placed in my dist folder after ng build.
From this I have achieved almost and redirect takes place according to the desktop/device(android,ipphone) to respective domains like for desktop to web.domain.com and for mobile m.domain.com.
But there is an issue for my child/secondary routes- on reload suppose web.domain.com/xyz it redirects to me request url not found error.

Below is my code for htaccess:
for mobile dist:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://web.domain.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

and for desktop dist folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://m.domain.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

I am not able to figure for my child/secondary routes like web.domain.com/xyz or web.domain.com/abc reload it redirects me to url not found error.

Comment: Your RewriteRules in both places match a completely empty path only, meaning only if the root URL was requested, does this do anything in the first place. If your problem is with requesting `/xyz`, then what you have shown should not have any influence on that at all. This must be something in combination with the rest of your rewriting, that you presumably have in place for your general app routing.

Comment: @CBroe removing htacess file from dist, runs fine for my secondary/child routes.
And these are the only condition that I have mentioned on htacess